# Reading data in parts from server using InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bytearrayoutputstream

I am developing an Android application for which I need to download large amount of data from the web servers.

**Code to read files is as follows:**

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(myURLConnection.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        byte[] d = result.toByteArray();
```

But with the above code, I getting the **Out-of-Memory** error on the line "**result.write(buffer, 0, length);**" on Android devices.

I have following questions:

1. What coding changes are required to read data in **chunks** from web
   server using **InputStream**?
2. Are there any alternate solutions which can perform **memory efficient** data reading from web server?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you should use `FileOutput` stream instead, otherwise you are collecting all the data into memory ... and then out-of-memory is inevitable....

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you please elaborate more about your suggestion using FileOutputStream? Should I use it instead of ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: What I am suggesting is that you should write your data to file system, as apparently it is too big to fit into memory. So, yes basically I am suggesting   using FileOutputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream (or you could even combine them). The problem is that your `result` is constantly growing ...and you don't want that. So read fixed amount od data from input stream, write it to the disk  - repeat. Also, may be this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819100/android-fileoutputstream-location-save-file) may be helpful...